# Sony NEX-6: Transfering photos via wi-fi to Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, wireless, sony-nex

I have a NEX-6, which has wi-fi support.  I was able to transfer my pictures via wi-fi using Sony Play Memory bundled software.  But unfortunately, the software is nowhere close to Adobe Lightroom in terms of functionality.

Is is possible to transfer photos to Lightroom via wi-fi with the Sony Nex-6?  If possible, what are steps?

Answer (score 1):

If the NEX-6 appears as a camera/storage media via wifi to your compter system, then Lightroom can import from it. However, in the case that the NEX-6 does not appear as a standard system Lightroom knows about then you can use Lightroom's Auto Import feature to automatically import images from a folder that your Sony Play Memory program writes to. Simply use the Sony software to import the images to your computer, and have Lightroom watch that folder for new images. It will import them as usual, automatically.  Configure Auto Import via File>Auto Import.